# Is it possible for a non-self antigen to NOT be recognized by the body?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, immunology, immunity

The amazing diversity of antigens that the body can recognize (by virtue of T and B cells that express receptors complementary to them) is truly fascinating. The explanation mooted for this is the concept of V(D)J Recombination - somatic recombination creates a massive repertoire of TCRs and antibodies. As a result, any antigen, no matter how "foreign", hooks up with an immune cell triggering an immune response manifesting as a typical "cold".

I want to know if it is possible for this process of recombination to *miss* a particular antigen. In other words, can there be such an antigen which has *no* complementary antibody at all toward it?

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange! Have you ever heard about antibody (binding) affinity? Namely, the ability to "recognize" an antigen is not all-or-nothing property, but a continuum (which can be quantified via affinity constant).

Comment: @Domen I am not sure if I follow, could you explain?

Do you mean to say that an antibody needn't be "perfectly" complementary to an antigen, but can somehow modify itself to better fit in if it's almost complementary?

Comment: I just wanted to emphasize that there is a varying degree of antibody affinity, and asking for "no affinity" is slightly ill-defined. Moreover, note that [antigen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antigen) is _by definition_ something that can bind to a specific antibody. So I think your questions is more about whether there exists molecules that are not antigenic, right? In that case, look at [haptens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapten).

Comment: @Domen I referred the articles you linked, but I am sorry to say that I still do not understand. 

For example, there are thousands of molecules in our body which, by virtue of immune tolerance, do not "bind" to antibodies simply because they are tolerated. Thus these are not "antigens". My question is - is it possible for there to be a molecule which is NOT tolerated (and thus SHOULD be "antigenic" in that it should bind to an antibody) because no complimentary antibody to it has been synthesized by somatic recombination?

Comment: @A-big-neutron Yes. Just look at vaccines - they stimulate the immune system to recognize antigen(s) that it otherwise isn't recognizing, or isn't responding to quickly enough. As far as tolerance is concerned, human proteins generally aren't bound by naturally-occurring TCRs and antibodies. However, if you were to immunize a rabbit, for example, with that protein and adjuvants, it would create antibodies to it.